# How to create stacked rounded bottom bar menu item in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

[image: I want to create a bottom bar like this]

I have created the following block, but unable to get the result. The Code create custom bottom bar, but the edges are not transparent and icon should float. Please help me.

```
new Container(
          height: 300.0,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
              )
            ),
            child: new Center(
            child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
           )
         ),
        ),
```

Comment: you can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar

Comment: you can also check more packages related to bottombar
https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/